# How to create Tags using docusign PHP REST API

Tags: php, rest, docusignapi

I can use docusign login and send document to sign, but that is having tags created with website UI, how can tags be created dynamically through its REST API, actually I will be creating it in loop with database query. 
This is curret code.

`

```
// construct the authentication header:
$header = "<DocuSignCredentials><Username>" . $email . "</Username><Password>" . $password . "</Password><IntegratorKey>" . $integratorKey . "</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>";

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// STEP 1 - Login (to retrieve baseUrl and accountId)
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$url = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information";
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header"));

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if ( $status != 200 ) {
    echo "error calling webservice, status is:" . $status;
    exit(-1);
}

$response = json_decode($json_response, true);
$accountId = $response["loginAccounts"][0]["accountId"];
$baseUrl = $response["loginAccounts"][0]["baseUrl"];
curl_close($curl);

// --- display results
echo "\naccountId = " . $accountId . "\nbaseUrl = " . $baseUrl . "\n";

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// STEP 2 - Create and envelope using one template role (called "Signer1") and one recipient
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$data = array("accountId" => $accountId, 
    "emailSubject" => "DocuSign API - Signature Request from Template",
    "templateId" => $templateId, 
    "templateRoles" => array( 
            array( "email" => $email, "name" => $recipientName, "roleName" => $templateRoleName, 

                "tabStatuses" => array(

                        "tabStatus" => array(
                            0 => array( 
                                "tabLabel" => "lic_num",
                                "tabValue" => "1111"
                            ),
                            1 => array( 
                                "tabLabel" => "ubi_num",
                                "tabValue" => "2222"
                            ),
                            2 => array( 
                                "tabLabel" => "tra_nam",
                                "tabValue" => "Flakey"
                            )
                         )
                     ),
                        "tabs" => array(
                            "textTabs" => array (
                                                  array (
                                                    "tabLabel"=> "business",
                                                      "name" => "address",
                                                      "value" => "Address from DB",
                                                      "show" => "true",
                                                       "pageNumber"=> "1",
                                                        "documentId"=> "1",
                                                        "yPosition"=> "300",
                                                        "xPosition"=> "300",
                                                        "locked"=> false
                                                      )
                                                )
                                    )
                )
            ),
    "status" => "sent");                                                                    

$data_string = json_encode($data);  
$curl = curl_init($baseUrl . "/envelopes" );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string),
    "X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header" )                                                                       
);

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if ( $status != 201 ) {
    echo "error calling webservice, status is:" . $status . "\nerror text is --> ";
    print_r($json_response); echo "\n";
    exit(-1);
}

$response = json_decode($json_response, true);
$envelopeId = $response["envelopeId"];

// --- display results
echo "Document is sent! Envelope ID = " . $envelopeId . "\n\n";
```

?>`

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan have you seen code now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a sample that's taking advantage of a template (where tags are pre-created), while you can do composite template the easiest thing to start is just to upload document bytes and specify your tags manually.  Here is an example of how to do that: http://iodocs.docusign.com/APIWalkthrough/requestSignatureFromDocument

```
<?php

    // Input your info here:
    $email = "***";         // your account email
    $password = "***";      // your account password
    $integratorKey = "***";     // your account integrator key, found on (Preferences -> API page)
    $recipientName = "***";     // provide a recipient (signer) name
    $documentName = "***";      // copy document with same name into this directory!

    // construct the authentication header:
    $header = "<DocuSignCredentials><Username>" . $email . "</Username><Password>" . $password . "</Password><IntegratorKey>" . $integratorKey . "</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>";

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // STEP 1 - Login (to retrieve baseUrl and accountId)
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    $url = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information";
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header"));

    $json_response = curl_exec($curl);
    $status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    if ( $status != 200 ) {
        echo "error calling webservice, status is:" . $status;
        exit(-1);
    }

    $response = json_decode($json_response, true);
    $accountId = $response["loginAccounts"][0]["accountId"];
    $baseUrl = $response["loginAccounts"][0]["baseUrl"];
    curl_close($curl);

    //--- display results
    echo "\naccountId = " . $accountId . "\nbaseUrl = " . $baseUrl . "\n";

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // STEP 2 - Create an envelope with one recipient, one tab, and one document and send
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // the following request body will place 1 signature tab on the document you supply, located
    // 100 pixels to the right and 100 pixels down from the top left of the document
    $data = array (
            "emailSubject" => "DocuSign API - Signature Request on Document",
            "documents" => array( array( "documentId" => "1", "name" => $documentName)),
            "recipients" => array( "signers" => array(
                array(  "email" => $email,
                        "name" => $recipientName,
                        "recipientId" => "1",
                        "tabs" => array(
                            "signHereTabs" => array(
                                array( "xPosition" => "100",
                                       "yPosition" => "100",
                                       "documentId" => "1",
                                       "pageNumber" => "1" )
                            ))
                 ))
            ),
        "status" => "sent"
    );
    $data_string = json_encode($data);  

    $file_contents = file_get_contents($documentName);

    $requestBody = "\r\n"
    ."\r\n"
    ."--myboundary\r\n"
    ."Content-Type: application/json\r\n"
    ."Content-Disposition: form-data\r\n"
    ."\r\n"
    ."$data_string\r\n"
    ."--myboundary\r\n"
    ."Content-Type:application/pdf\r\n"
    ."Content-Disposition: file; filename=\"$documentName\"; documentid=1 \r\n"
    ."\r\n"
    ."$file_contents\r\n"
    ."--myboundary--\r\n"
    ."\r\n";

    // *** append "/envelopes" to baseUrl and as signature request endpoint
    $curl = curl_init($baseUrl . "/envelopes" );
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $requestBody);                                                                  
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
        'Content-Type: multipart/form-data;boundary=myboundary',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($requestBody),
        "X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header" )                                                                       
    );

    $json_response = curl_exec($curl);
    $status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    if ( $status != 201 ) {
        echo "error calling webservice, status is:" . $status . "\nerror text is --> ";
        print_r($json_response); echo "\n";
        exit(-1);
    }

    $response = json_decode($json_response, true);
    $envelopeId = $response["envelopeId"];

    //--- display results
    echo "Document is sent! Envelope ID = " . $envelopeId . "\n\n"; 
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, actually I already got that working before answer, but later due to some changes I am using `/templates` so not using `/envelopes` API Call. But accepting this answer.